# How do I upgrade using GIT?

Tags: version-control

From time to time, there will be minor and major updates to Drupal core. If the release is designated as a security update, we should apply the update as soon as we can. Otherwise, we may choose to apply the update at any time to receive the bug fixes it contains. There are also major release upgrades; we may want to apply these, so we have all the new and powerful features.

How do I upgrade using GIT?

Comment: [Drupal Tutorial - Upgrading Drupal Core on your websites with Git](http://www.strykerenterprise.com/blog/drupal-tutorial-upgrading-drupal-core-your-websites-git)

Comment: Is your site just tracked in git, or did your site start our as a proper clone of the drupal repo?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend installing and using Drush with GIT instead of only GIT when it comes to security or any other updates. It's really easy to update with drush.

```
drush up
```

will update everything

```
drush up modulename
```

will only update a module of your choosing

```
drush up drupal
```

will only update drupal core.

Comment: As Travis Johnston I would also recommend using Drush for updating. You could work with both Drush and Git at the same time.

Comment: The big downside of this is when you are using a patched core. drush will nuke the patches. A git only workflow helps with thisv

Comment: Yes and no, for me anyways. I only ever have a max of 2 patches in my entire build (which I leave out of git repo) so it's never been a big deal, that's what custom modules are for ;). You could also use drush in a different branch and merge in changes to your patched branch to solve patching problems.